# How do I center the text of the links in this bootstrap navbar when it collapses?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want the links in the dropdown to be centered.

Code:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top bg clean-navbar">
  <div class="container logo" style="position: relative;">
    <a class="navbar-brand text-left d-block float-left d-xl-flex logo" href="assets/img/kol-logoldpi.svg"><img class="kibrislogo" height="50" src='assets/img/kol-logoldpi2.svg' /></a><button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navcol-1"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link active" href="index.html">Paketler</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" href="features.html">Kampanyalar</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" href="pricing.html">sss</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" href="about-us.html">Hizmet Noktalari</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" href="contact-us.html"><strong>İLETIŞIM</strong></a></li>
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" href="contact-us.html" style="color: rgba(207,14,14,0.5);">TR/ENG</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <img class="logo" style="position: absolute; right: -7%; height: 70px;" src="assets/img/kol-ccldpi.svg" alt="">
  </div>
</nav>
```

The text is shifted to the left as you can see.

Comment: There are bootstrap 4 classes to align your text as per your requirement. To center you can use `text-center`.Please have a look at the below snippet

Answer (score 0):

apply bootstrap 4 class `text-center` to your `ul`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
   <nav class="navbar navbar-full navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container logo" style="position: relative;">
      <a class="navbar-brand text-left d-block float-left d-xl-flex logo" href="assets/img/kol-logoldpi.svg"><img class="kibrislogo" height="50" src='assets/img/kol-logoldpi2.svg' /></a><button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navcol-1"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto text-center">
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link active" href="index.html">Paketler</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" href="features.html">Kampanyalar</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" href="pricing.html">sss</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" href="about-us.html">Hizmet Noktalari</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" href="contact-us.html"><strong>İLETIŞIM</strong></a></li>
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" href="contact-us.html" style="color: rgba(207,14,14,0.5);">TR/ENG</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <img class="logo" style="position: absolute; right: -7%; height: 70px;" src="assets/img/kol-ccldpi.svg" alt="">
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add another class to your li like

```
<li class="nav-item navLink" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" href="contact-us.html" style="color: rgba(207,14,14,0.5);">TR/ENG</a></li>
```

then provide css like

```
.navLink{
   text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the bootstrap class

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0 text-center">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" tabindex="-1" >About</a>
      </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```